# Откуда произошло слово "приспичить"?

Tags: этимология

Приспичило - значит, очень сильно, позарез надо. А при чем тут спички? 
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 2):

Это не от слова "спички", а от "спица"(кстати, спичка - от "спица"), как утверждает словарь Фасмера, приводя мнение пр.Преображенского. Я с ним согласна: когда спицей тебя кольнут - приспичит, пожалуй, это хороший стимул что-то делать, появится острая необходимость, а пока не кольнуло - не очень-то и надо.

Comment: Действительно, очень острая (точнее - колючая) необходимость))